# How to call JS parent-methods without prototypical inheritance

Tags: javascript, inheritance

I'm working on a big project and decided against prototyping for inheritance (I wanted more control over `var` and `this.*` access).

Anyways, I have classes that look like this:

FirstScene.prototyp

```
FirstScene.prototype = Object.create(_SceneCanvas.prototype)
FirstScene.prototype.constructor = FirstScene

function FirstScene(){
     var arguments = [/*args*/]
     _SceneCanvas.apply(this, arguments)



     this.bar = function(){ /*do other stuff*/ }
}
```

If I was in `foo()` or `bar()` and wanted to call the parent method, how would I go about doing that? I tried some code that looked like `_SceneCanvas.prototype.foo.call(params)` to no avail.

Thanks!

Comment: The concept "parent method" doesn't really apply for "foo"; it's a local function in the constructor.

Comment: Also I don't understand what you mean by saying you decided against prototyping for inheritance, but then you go on to post code that uses prototype inheritance.

Comment: @Pointy my functions are not in the form of `FirstScene.prototype.foo = function()` Am I missing something?

Comment: Yes, that's just one way of putting properties on a prototype. You're still using prototype inheritance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In JavaScript the common practice is to get a reference to the old function and call it from within the new function.

```
var bar = this.bar;
this.bar = function () {
  bar.call(this);
  // ...
};
```

Please check out [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/56oqqkq4/1/) to see it in action.

Comment: ... probably `bar.call(this)` to make sure there's a context.

Comment: So why does `this.bar()` call the parent method instead of the immediate one? (Also, your solution works. Thanks!)

Comment: It is interpreted sequentially. When `bar` is assigned `this.bar`, `this.bar` is the parent's `bar` function. The next line then overwrites `this.bar` to be a new function. If you move `var bar = this.bar;` to after you overwrite it, you'll get the new function.